# Is USB type c vulnerable to BadUSB?

Tags: storage, usb, badusb

Consider the new SanDisk ultra dual type c flash drive. Would that be safer once computers start to come with type c ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB C is just a different physical port standard. It implements the same USB 2.0 / 3.0 interface. BadUSB revolves around reprogramming the USB micro-controller to act as a human interface device and input commands when it is plugged in. USB C is as vulnerable as any other USB port standard.